# How can I install perf 3.4.25?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, performance, perf

By installing `perf` using

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-3.2.0.23
```

gave me

> perf version 3.2.14

How can I install `perf` 3.4.25?

Is it related to kernel version?

I found source here http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/tools/perf/
but there is no way to download it.

which version kernel comes with **perf 3.4.25?**

Answer (score 2):

The perf tool is directly shipped with the kernel and located under the [tools/perf/ directory](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/perf).

Comment: which version kernel comes with perf 3.4.25?

Comment: The perf version seems to correspond with the kernel version, so you need kernel 3.4.25. Although it is still unclear why you need that exact version.

Comment: I need to test that specific version, but when I installed linux-tools-3.2.0.23 in kernel 3.2.0.23 I got perf version 3.2.14.

Comment: The *tools/perf/util/* directory contains a script called [PERF-VERSION-GEN](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/perf/util/PERF-VERSION-GEN) which uses `git` and a little magic to generate the version string.

Comment: Again, why do you need that exact version? It is tied to the kernel version, so you can't (meanigfully) test a new version on an old kernel/system.